# If $L/E$ is separable then $L/F$ and $F/E$ are separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

My professor gave the Theorem: If $L/F$ and $F/E$ are (not necessarily finite) extensions, then $L/E$ is separable if and only if $L/F$ is separable and $F/E$ is separable.
He proved that: If $L/F$ and $F/E$ are separable, then $L/E$ is separable.
And said that the other if then statement is "obvious", i.e. If $L/E$ is separable then $L/F$ and $F/E$ are separable.
But I just don't see how this is "obvious", I can't really prove it either.

Any help for this is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've only been able to do the first part. So suppose that $L/E$ is separable. Now all $\alpha\in L$ are separable over $E$, so then any $\alpha\in K$ is also separable over $E$. Thus $F/E$ is separable. I don't know how to prove that $L/F$ is separable.

Comment: Take $\alpha\in L$. Then you know that $\alpha$ is separable over $E$. Look at the definition of separable, and think about why $\alpha$ should be separable over $F\supseteq E$.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ divides the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$; so if the latter has no repeated roots, neither does the former.